How to build dynamic elastic query from array using elastic dsl
I want to build a query like this:
GET elasticIndexExample/_search
{
  "query": {
    "bool":{
      "must": [
        {
          "range": {
            "creationDate": {
              "gte": "2004-08-02T05:00:00.000Z",
              "lte": "2004-10-02T05:00:00.000Z",
              "boost": 2.0
            }
          }
        },
        {
          "bool":{
            "should": [
              {
                "term":{
                  "customerName": "Wallmart"
                }
              },
              {
                "term":{
                  "customerName": "Petco"
                }
              }
            ],
            "minimum_should_match": 1
          }
        },
        {
          "bool": {
            "should": [
              {
                "term":{
                  "state": "OH"
                }
              },
              {
                "term":{
                  "state": "MI"
                }
              }
            ],
            "minimum_should_match": 1
          }
        }
      ]
    }
  }
}

So this will return all records that are within a date that are either from wallmart or petco that were in Ohio or Michigan. This elastic query works, and gets exactly what I want. Only issue is I am trying to plug something like this in an API that takes in arbitray input for what states and names to plug into those bool:should arrays.
This is what I am doing now (for only one should array, the other is the same)
// This list will hold ALL should queries
List<QueryDescriptor<ElasticLoad>> shouldQueryList = new();

QueryDescriptor<ElasticLoad> customerNamesShouldQuery = new();
if (customerPOs.Count > 0)
{
    customerNameShouldQuery .Bool(boolQuery =>
        boolQuery.Should(should =>
        {
            foreach (var customerName in customerNames)
            {
                should.Term(term =>
                    term.Field(field => field.CustomerName).Value(CustomerName)
                );
            }
        })
        .MinimumShouldMatch(1);
    );
    shouldQueryList.Add(customerNamesShouldQuery);
}

var lookAtShouldQueryList = client.RequestResponseSerializer.SerializeToString(
    shouldQueryList,
    formatting: Elastic.Transport.SerializationFormatting.Indented
);


return shouldQueryList;

but when I look at the json at the end I only see the last term added (so when I pass ["wallmart", "petco"] it makes (NOTE: Missing petco):
"bool":{
    "should": [
        {
          "term":{
            "customerName": "Wallmart"
          }
        }
    ],
    "minimum_should_match": 1
}

how can I dynamically add those term queries to the bool query in the foreach loop? (or if that is an x y delema, how should I go about this differently)
Thank you in advance! :)
